# Get the handle of the form the mouse is currently on in VB.net

Tags: winforms, mouse, handle

Is it possible to get a forms handle (regardless if it is my program or not) based on position (i.e. the mouse position)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "WindowFromPoint")]
static public extern IntPtr WindowFromPoint(Point Point);
```

and pass `Cursor.Position` to get the handle over the current 'visible' window.